# How can the Adobe AIR installer itself require AIR?

Tags: installation, adobe, air

I downloaded the AIR_Win_installer_files.zip file in order to do a side-car AIR installation.  I created a directory (AIR_bundle) and unzipped the downloaded file into that.  In that directory, I end up with:

```
Adobe AIR Installer.exe
Adobe AIR/
```

where the latter is a sub-folder containing lots of other files.  On the command-line, I execute the exe file passing only the -silent option, and I get an error dialog that says:

> This application requires a version of
>   Adobe AIR which cannot be found. 
>   Please download the latest version of
>   the runtime from
>   http://www.adobe.com/getair, or
>   contact the application author for an
>   updated version.

How can the AIR installer itself require AIR?  It's AIR I'm trying to install in the first place.

Note: this is **NOT** the standard AIR installer.  This is the special installer you can use if you get a special license from Adobe to distribute AIR with your application.

FYI: I've been referring to the "ADOBE AIR 1.5 Runtime Redistribution Instructions" document that says in part:

## Silent installation

...
To run the Adobe AIR installer silently, start the Adobe AIR installer with the following command line options:

`-silent {-eulaAccepted ( -location  ) -desktopShortcut -programMenu} path`

...

To install or update the runtime only, use the `-silent` option without specifying a path or any other options.

Comment: BTW: doing this using the Mac version of the Adobe AIR Installer works correctly as described in the documentation.  The Windows version therefore seems like a bug, but you'd think that would be too glaring a bug to go unnoticed by Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

See this support KB from Adobe for the reason/fix:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/764383?tstart=60

Comment: I wasn't using a G4 processor.

Answer (score 0):

It requires you to install Air Framework. The installer is clearly written using the Air Framework. So you should download and install Air Framework first to be able to run it. Installer file is just an installer and does not contain the Air Framework.

You are also going to need to install Air Framework for the client you wish to distribute your application before running the Air Application Installer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install an air application the command string should be something like.

```
AdobeAIRInstaller.exe -silent -eulaAccepted -desktopShortcut "desktop_mv_1.1.1.air"
```

This is to install Chatter silently with a desktop shortcut.

The AdobeAIRInstaller.exe installs air applications as well as AIR runtime if it is not already installed. It doesn't just install AIR as far as I can tell.

I downloaded the AIR installer file from adobe [Adobe Runtime Distribution](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html) And this gets me the file's needed.